# Object #<Object> has no method 'easeInOutCubic'

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a switchbutton using this method stated in this page http://olance.github.io/jQuery-switchButton/ but I encountered certain error which states, "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'easeInOutCubic' " ...what could be the problem with this?..Please help...thanks!..^_^

Comment: sounds like you are missing the jQuery easings library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you're missing `jQuery` easing plugin here, try to add this after including jQuery:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```